# DELETE FROM not working for multiple tables - clueless with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I have three tables

workplaces with a field id (the one of which i want to delete the associated data), and a participantlist_id that identifies the participant list.

participantlist - just list_id and name

participantlist_links - with list_id and participant_id

the query that i'm trying to use is this:

```
DELETE FROM workplaces,
participantlist,
participantlist_links 
WHERE workplaces.id =  '8' AND 
      workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist_links.list_id AND  
      workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist.list_id
```

but i get:

MySQL said:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE workplaces.id='8' AND workplaces.participantlist_id = participant' at line 3

any ideas?

SOLUTION:

```
    DELETE t1, t2, t3
    FROM workplaces AS t1
    LEFT JOIN participantlist AS t2 ON t1.participantlist_id = t2.list_id
    LEFT JOIN participantlist_links AS t3 ON t2.list_id = t3.list_id
    WHERE t1.id = '8'
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the related row form all the 3 tables? Or just from 1 table? Or from 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN to delete from multiple tables like this:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered putting `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign keys?
This way when you delete the row from workspace, the other rows will be automatically deleted as well.

See this link for more information:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Otherwise you'd have to use seperate DELETE FROM queries to delete them all.

It's smart to use a transaction while executing these deletes. So if anything goes wrong you can rollback your changes:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM ......;
DELETE FROM ......;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DELETE workplaces, participantlist, participantlist_links FROM workplaces,
participantlist,
participantlist_links 
WHERE workplaces.id =  '8' AND 
      workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist_links.list_id AND  
      workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist.list_id
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html), the multiple-table forms of `DELETE` have different syntax to that which you're using.  You want:

```
DELETE workplaces, participantlist, participant_links
FROM   workplaces
  JOIN participantlist
    ON workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist.list_id
  JOIN participantlist_links
    ON workplaces.participantlist_id = participantlist_links.list_id
WHERE  workplaces.id = '8'
```